# Are sink topics mandatory in a topology?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my application, I need Kafka Streams features to join, transform and aggregate in a state store. However, I don't need a sink topic as my application is the last link in the events chain.

Do I absolutely need to have a sink topic in order to have a valid topology or is it fine not to have one?

Answer (score 2):

You need a terminal operator (a Sink Processor), not necessarily a *topic*. For example, `foreach`, but ignore the data that's consumed.

For state store purposes, using `toTable` DSL would be a terminal operation, and this will create a changelog topic.

Comment: Is "action" a Kafka Streams term or do you just mean "side effect"?

Comment: Technically, it's referred as a Sink processor in the documentation. Building a statestore will create a changelog topic

Comment: I just read this about the sink processors in the [official docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html): *Sink Processor: A sink processor is a special type of stream processor that does not have down-stream processors. It sends any received records from its up-stream processors to a specified Kafka topic.* does that mean a sink topic is mandatory?

Comment: Actually I don't need a sink topic at all, I just want that state store to be requested on-demand

Comment: Like I said, a statestore will create a topic that ends in `-changelog` since the store itself needs to be built from a compacted kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not clearly stated in the docs, it is fine to have a "sinkless" topology.

There is no `TopologyException` in the source code such as "No sink topic in the topology".

When trying to run a "sinkless" topology, it works just fine, `topology.describe().toString()` gives the following output:

```
  Sub-topology: 4
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000034 (topics: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000030-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000031
    Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000031 (stores: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000030])
      --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000035
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000034
    Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000035 (stores: [])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000031
```